# How to get image of specific size using python?

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, capture

I am trying to get pictures from my camera using open cv I am using this code to access camera and save images in a folder.

```py
import cv2
i = 0
#i = int(input(" "))
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,0)
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\naman.sharma\Desktop\Image_dataset\nm_result_{}.png".format(i), frame)
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works well but I am getting an image of size (600,480) which is very big for the project I am doing.

Is there any specific way to capture images with a certain size. I am trying to capture picture of (250,200).

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You can use cv2.resize to change the image size (some devices support various capture sizes, but you will probably not get a frame size 250x200 in any of them).

Comment: But will  cv2.resize  rupture the image quality?

Comment: There are several interpolation methods for the resize. Each will potentially yield a different result. You can check which of them works best for you. See: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html.

Comment: Thanks will check and will tell you the results.

Comment: @wohlstad thanks your answer worked for me and i didnt lost to much of picture quality as well. Can post it as an answer so that i can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some devices support various capture sizes, but it is unlikely that your device will support a 250x200 frame size.

Instead of changing the capture size, you can **resize the captured frame** using [**`cv2.resize`**](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d).
The last parameter **`interpolation`** controls the resampling method. The available options are listed [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121).

Usage example (with bicubic interpolation):

```
ret,frame = cap.read()
resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (250,200), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```